# cast object Task<ActionResult<T>> where T is Type variable

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection

I'm making a unit test class with a config file.
I have similar object (same interfaces) to check.

At a point of my code I get *Task<ActionResult<OneOfMyObjectType>>* object by using reflection. my issue is to read the Result I have to cast this Object First but I can't use *Task<IActionResult>* or *Task<ActionResult<InferfaceOfTheObject>>*. the compiler only allow me to cast to the Specific class that is used. (if I don't I have an *InvalidCastException*).

How Can I do this?

extract of code of my tests  :

```
dynamic objectType = Type.GetType($"{ClassName},{Assembly}")!;
Type ControllerActionType = Type.GetType($"{ControllerActionsClasseName}, {Assembly}")!;
MethodInfo info = ControllerActionType.GetMethod(methodName!)!;
var myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(ControllerActionType, new object[] { context });
var testObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(operation!.Data, objectType);
var actionResult = info!.Invoke(myInstance, new object[] { testObject })!;
var castedActionResult = "** I'm blocked here**";
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and why do you think reflection is the solution? An `ActionResult<>` is something that's returned by controller actions. A `Task<ActionResult...>>` is something returned by asynchronous controller actions. All asynchronous methods return a `Task`-derived object. You have to await that task or use `.Result` to get the method's result.  Why are you trying to call the controller action through reflection?

Comment: You can't.  With a controller the action Result is analyzed and matched against a class object to determine what class needs to be processed.  So making it generic the library is trying to match a generic class against an actual class and will never match.  It is like putting the "cart before the horse".

Comment: in the end, I direclty get the Result Property Value without casting. (see my answer at the end of the page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information, my guess is that *Controller.Method* returns a *Task*, and that you're trying to cast the result from the method as *Task<ActionResult>*.

All you need to here is two casts, one that matches the return type from the method, and one on the Task's result that is the expected underlying type.

```
var actionResultTask = (Task<IActionResult>)info!.Invoke(myInstance, new object[] { testObject })!;
var castedActionResult = (ActionResult<InferfaceOfTheObject>) = actionResultTask.Value;
```

The point here, is that without a lot more reflection, the generic parameters must match.  So if the ActionResult from method was declared with the interface, then it has to be casted `ActionResult<InterfaceOfTheObject>`, if it was declared using an implementation then that cast has to be used instead.

If you're unsure of a type of a property, but are confident that its return type implements a relevant interface, then you can use the following method to get the property value by reflection.  You should be able to use this to get any property value.

```
public void SomeTestMethod() {
    /* ... */
    var methodResult = (Task)info.Invoke(myInstance, new object[] {});
    var actionResult = GetGenericPropertyValue<IActionResult>(methodResult, "Result");
    var actionResultValue = GetGenericPropertyValue<InferfaceOfTheObject>(actionResult, "Value");
}
    
public static T GetGenericPropertyValue<T>(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    return (T)obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, casting with Task\<IAcitonResult> throw a castexception. 
finally for the moment I succes with using the get property. it's very bad I think but this works : 
`var action = info!.Invoke(myInstance, new object[] { testObject })!;
            var actionResult  = action!.GetType().GetProperty("Result")!.GetValue(action);
            var result = actionResult!.GetType().GetProperty("Result")!.GetValue(actionResult);
            var isOkResult = result as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult;`
then I check if isOkResult is null or not.